# Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object in Redhat

Tags: java

I am using Redhat 6. I am in strange problem.
I was working with java 1.6. I updated my system with `yum updated` automatically openjdk 1.8 got install. I removed the package fro UI.
Now when I typed `java -version`. I get this error

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object.
```

I thought my java is corrupted and I remove java using `yum remove java*`. Again I installed java.

I downloaded the `bin` file of java 1.6 and extracted it in my home folder. edited `.bash_profile` and gave the path.

run `.bash_profile` Using `. .bash_profile`

Now when I type
`java -version` I get

> java version "1.6.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_45-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

but when i restart my system and again I type 
java -version I get the same error saying

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

How do i resolve it?

Comment: See if you have Gnu CLASSPATH installed, and if so remove it.

Comment: @EJP sorry I dont have any Idea about that could you please tell me how do i remove this?

Comment: @EJP when I typed `echo $CLASSPATH` i dont see any out put

Comment: It's a product, a software installation.